# How to I idiomatically do Inversion of Control for routes in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'd like to know the idiomatic correct way to link two sub projects together

My current situation is that I am refactoring a big website (hundreds of .scala and .scala.html files) into a handful of smaller sub projects. Let's take a concrete example

There is a subproject that deals with Accounts, Groups and Membership. This sub project is mostly self contained. But on the group webpage, I want to put a button to allow a member of that group to do an action. In this concrete example 'Issue a document'.

There is a second subproject that declares this action. This subproject knows about Groups, but it is primarily concerned with issuing documents. There is a lot of logic and web pages around that. There are perhaps only two or three buttons in the 'Accounts, Groups and Membership' project that should end up coming into this project

Now if this was a Scala class dependency problem I have a wealth of tools. Typically I would use some form of inversion of control to allow a client class  to inject the buttons.

Ideas I have explored

1: I can put hard coded routes into the application.conf. This is actually trivially easy, intention revealing (although a little obscure) but isn't type safe.

2: I can have a method on the controllers in the 'Accounts, Groups and membership' project that allows me to programatically add routes. This is doable but messy.

What is the idiomatically correct Play way to do it?